# How to write condition in [ngContainer] for styling

Tags: html, css, angular

I have this piece of code:

`[containerStyle]="{'width': '200%' : '100%'', 'height':'100%'}"`

Now, I want the width to vary according to a variable `searchValue` value that I have defined in my `ts` file. So, I tried the below code:

`[containerStyle]="{'width':( (searchValue === 'phone') ? '200%' : '100%'), 'height':'100%'}"`

Now the problem is:

If I try the below code :

```
[containerStyle]="{'width':( (searchValue === 'phone') ? '200%' : '100%'), 'height':'100%'}"
```

the width is always set to 100% .

And if I try

```
[containerStyle]="{'width':( (searchValue === phone) ? '200%' : '100%'), 'height':'100%'}"
```

the width is always set to 200%.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please create a working example like stackblitz ?

Comment: Can you try [style.width.%]="searchValue.toLowerCase() === 'phone' ? '200%' : '100%'"
                                            [style.height.%]="'100%'"

Comment: What is the searchValue?

Comment: @iamentafaz its a string.

Answer (score 1):

> **In your case I hope the following code will work:**

```
[ngStyle]= "{'width': (searchValue.toLowerCase()  === 'phone') ? '200%' : '100%', 'height': '100%'}"
```

> **If you are using ng-container then you can use the following code**

```
<ng-container [ngStyle]= "{'width': (searchValue.toLowerCase()  === 'phone') ? '200%' : '100%', 'height': '100%'}"></ng-container>
```